# is it possible to implement part of interface in a class, and the rest in a subclass?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
interface ParentInterface {
  foo(): string;
  print(): void;
}

class ParentClass implements ParentInterface {
  print() { console.log(this.foo()); }
}

class ChildClassA extends ParentClass {
  foo() { return "foo-A"; }
}

class ChildClassB extends ParentClass {
  foo() { return "foo-B"; }
}
```

Of course this isn't valid typescript, because ParentClass doesn't implement ParentInterface's method 'foo()';

Is it possible to structure it in a different way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the parent class `abstract`

```
abstract class ParentClass implements ParentInterface {
  print() { console.log(this.foo()); }

  abstract foo(): string
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApyhcBJc15LIDeAsAFDLIwD21AFAJQBcyAzmFKAOYDc5lAB07hGLAG7VgAEz5kAvuXJwARuyiIwyBABs4rVmgxYwAYV37kwALYDtEK8YPpMOPLEQpSFZENBhGxFrUIKzUdgB02tRcdGAAFsCs4TT0DAw8yApk-MgqahpUtKJsHNzkWeQ6egYmCdpSZtUAgsgQAB6QIFJORuCNFl6UKQFEyJhgAK5QIMgARCkAtE2zGVkVZFUWtcD1-awAQq0dWN2GLqbmBoOFqYHjUzPztAv7K5nlQA)